# How to install Google play services in Custom Android ROM(ETM machine)

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-rom

I am using ETM machine to make a payment receipt in my android application.My android app is having google Signin which requires google services so when I use my app on ETM machine it will give an error.

So my question is how we can add google play services in ETM machine

Answer (score 0):

The manufacturers of this device, and the creators of its Android ROM, will need to [license Google Play Services from Google](https://source.android.com/compatibility/contact-us#for-business-inquiries).